# IOS mobile automation

Tags: appium-ios

I am new to IOS automation testing. I have to install appium for automation on actual physical device. I have followed a number of links but I am still confused. I have installed appium and xcode. But when I run appium inspector I always get error 'Could not launch Appium Inspector'. What could be the possible cause? Also can someone suggest a link which I can follow for appium set up on MAC.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very basic list of things you need to have to make Appium work for iOS:

---

It's helpful to use Homebrew to install some of these items.

https://brew.sh/

---

First you need to have ruby version 2.2 or higher to utilize the newest appium. I would suggest you use a ruby manager like RVM to install this Ruby.

\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable

Then install a ruby version above 2.2 (I personally default to 2.4.0):

rvm install 2.2.0

you can set a default rvm to use for convenience:

rvm default 2.2.0

If you don't set the rvm default you will have to use the "rvm use *rubyversion*" command every time you open a terminal.

---

Node.js: Essential, can not do without.

brew install node

(Note: DO NOT INSTALL WITH SUDO)

---

Appium Desktop: Convenient implementation of appium for building test cases. Uses a GUI and has inspector build in.

https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop

---

Appium CLI: command line Appium which is best for running multiple devices at once.

npm install -g appium

npm install -g appium-doctor

Check the Doctor: You can use appium doctor to diagnose what next steps you need to do next. Run it with the --ios or --android tags to find out what you need for each of these operating systems. You'll have to make adjustments to your .bash_profile so Appium can find your JDK folder among other things.

---

Authorize iOS testing on your computer:

npm install -g authorize-ios

sudo authorize-ios

---

Carthage: required to automate after Xcode 8

brew install carthage

brew update carthage

---

Hopefully this will help to diagnose what is going on with your set up. If you're using ruby to do your automation scripts don't forget to actually download the appium_lib gem:

sudo gem install appium_lib

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Check this out latest appium desktop :

AppiumDesktop1.1.0beta4 iOS setup - Inspector and Record the scripts,

Link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2_xHmofGgUE

If you face any issue please comment it.